# Including anchor tag validation in HTML Validation logic

Tags: javascript, html, replace, tags

I've written a piece of code for my system that checks whether or not a string has proper opening ("<") and closed (">") brackets for any HTML tag. For example, if the string looks like this:

```
<i>hello<i>
```

my logic throws an error because there is no proper closing tag `(</i>)` in the string.

I am trying to incorporate validation for any anchor tags in this as well. Currently, if there are any properly formatted anchor tags present in the string, my code throws an error. For example, if a string includes something like this:

`"<a href=https://example.com>Website</a>"`

my logic thinks that there should be a matching closing tag somewhere after the "< a href=," but obviously that's not how an anchor tag is structured. How can I incorporate this into my current logic for all anchor tags? Here is what I have right now, but this only works for simple HTML tags (ex: `<b></b>, <i></i>`, etc.):

```
var errMsg = "";
var message = "";
var text = "<a href=https://example.com>Website</a>"
var regex = /<[^>]+>/g;
var foundArr = text.match(regex);
var size = foundArr.length;
var reset = false;

for (var i = 0; i <= size; i++) {

    if (reset) {
        i = 0;
    }
    reset = false;
    var arr1 = foundArr[i] + "";

    if (arr1.indexOf("/>") >= 0) {

        foundArr.splice(foundArr.indexOf(arr1), 1);
        reset = true;
        continue;
    } else {
        var words = arr1.split('<');
        var x = '</' + words[1];

        for (var j = i + 1; j < foundArr.length; j++) {
            var arr2 = foundArr[j];
            if (x == arr2) {
                foundArr.splice(foundArr.indexOf(arr1), 1);
                foundArr.splice(foundArr.indexOf(arr2), 1);
                reset = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    size = foundArr.length;
}
if (foundArr.length > 0) {
    message = "<li>" + "The text has invalid tags: " + foundArr.toString().replace(/</g, "").replace(/>/g, "") + " </li>";
}

console.log(message)
```

Comment: Generally, it's not a good idea to use regular expressions for parsing/validating HTML. HTML (or more generally, XML) syntax is too complicated to be nicely handled by a regex.

Comment: You'll enjoy this: `<b class="<i'm screwed>">oops!</b>`. That is why you want to use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).

Comment: I'm just learning, this is similar to a Leetcode problem for me. I know it's kind of useless in the real world, so I am just wondering how I can do this given the context of what I've done so far.

Comment: Learning is never useless! There is an amazing book on regex: Mastering Regular Expressions by Jeffrey Friedl.